# Eclipse file not found error - Despite file showing up in the package explorer

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting a file not found error in eclipse, i am trying to read a file called input.txt, and the file is present in the project folder alongside the class.

I have refreshed the folder in eclipse itself and it is showing up on the project explorer on the left hand side, but when i try to run the program i get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: input.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at CourseWorkClass.main(CourseWorkClass.java:14)
```

I should note that the code was working fine earlier on a different computer, but I since copied the code into a new project and now it will not work.

Comment: try keeping it in the top folder of the project

Comment: thanks a lot it works just fine now, but do you know why i had to move it, because previously it was alongside the class and it worked fine. Could it be that im user a newer version of eclipse?

Comment: how did you executed the code earlier? from command line?

Comment: i used the green run button in the eclipse program, same as before.

Comment: really tough to say now. depends how your eclipse project/package structure is

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse picks the file from the top folder if the file path is relative. So try moving the file to project's top folder

Comment: any idea why it worked before when it was further into the folders alongside the actual class file ?

Comment: share the earlier folder structure, how it was imported in eclipse